Fluent pagination in aws lambda function
We currently have a business logic inside of a lambda functions which queues events after paginating a list of users.

const spreadSiteUserEvents = async (
  authToken: IAuthToken,
  siteAsset: ISiteAssets,
  sourceEvent: IOrganizationActionEventSource
) => {
  let hasNextPage = true;
  let nextPage = 0;
  const eventsStats: { successful: number; failed: number; } = {
    successful: 0,
    failed: 0,
  };

  while (hasNextPage) {
    const users = await getUserIds(authToken.jwttoken, siteId, {
      page: nextPage,
      size: PAGE_SIZE,
    });

    if (!isEmpty(users.content)) {
      await Promise.allSettled(
        chunk(users.content, BATCH_MESSAGE_SIZE).map((chunkedUsers, index) =>
          queueUserEvents(chunkedUsers, siteAsset, sourceEvent)
        )
      );
    }
    hasNextPage = !users.last;
    nextPage++;
  }

  logger.info(
    `Total(Successful:${eventsStats.successful}, Failed:${eventsStats.failed}) events have been spreaded for the site(${sourceEvent.site.id}/${sourceEvent.site.name})`,
    { siteId: sourceEvent.site.id }
  );
};


Honestly, this see a bit of overkill and there is a slight chance that the function will timeout.

What can I do to avoid timeout ?
Is there any other alternative way to do the same ?

So far I have a theory of putting all this logic in a step function and integrate the step function with this lambda function which is spreading the events. But I am unable to put my theory in practice. The entire code base is written in aws-cdk
